# RJAGS compilation with categorical variable throws index out of range error

Tags: r, bayesian, categorical-data, rjags, bayesglm

**Background**
Trying to model `volume` of bikers in a rail trail which is less for a `weekday` as compared to a weekend. `RailTrail` from `mosaicData` contains data collected by the Pioneer Valley Planning Commission on the usage of a local rail-trail. For each of 90 days, they recorded the rail-trail `volume` (number of users) and whether it was a `weekday` (TRUE if yes and FALSE otherwise).

**Model**

Yi = trail volume (# of users) on day i
Xi = 1 for weekdays, 0 for weekends.

*Likelihood*

- Yi ∼ N(mi,s^2)
- mi =a+bXi

*Priors*

- a ∼ N(400,100^2)
- b ∼ N(0,200^2)
- s ∼ Unif(0,200)

**Code**

Trying to implement this in R as follows:

```r
library(rjags)
library(mosaicData)

data(RailTrail)

# DEFINE the model    
rail_model_1 <- "model{
    # Likelihood model for Y[i]
    for(i in 1:length(Y)) {
      Y[i] ~ dnorm(m[i], s^(-2))
      m[i] <- a + b[X[i]]
    }

    # Prior models for a, b, s
    a ~ dnorm(400, 100^(-2))
    b[1] <- 0
    b[2] ~ dnorm(0, 200^(-2))
    s ~ dunif(0, 200)
}"
```

Attempting to compile the model above using the following code:

```r
# COMPILE the model
rail_jags_1 <- jags.model(
  textConnection(rail_model_1),
  data = list(Y = RailTrail$volume, X = RailTrail$weekday),
  inits = list(.RNG.name = "base::Wichmann-Hill", .RNG.seed = 10)
)
```

**Error**

However, I am getting the following error in my attempt to compile:

```r
Error in jags.model(textConnection(rail_model_1), data = list(Y = RailTrail$volume,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 5.
Index out of range taking subset of  b
```

**Question**

Can you please help me with what is wrong here? I tested this in Ubuntu 20.04, MacOS Catalina as well as RStudio Cloud - same error. `rjags.version()` is `4.3.0`.

Comment: I don't follow what you are doing with the `b` parameter; do you want `m[i] <- a + b*X[i]` and to define the prior as `b ~ dnorm(0, 200^(-2))`

Comment: `a` = typical weekend volume
`a + b` = typical weekday volume

`b` is the difference between weekday and weekend. b has 2 levels: `b[1]`, `b[2]`. `b[1]` is manually set to 0, and `b[2] ~ dnorm(0, 200^(-2))`

Comment: or you could model them separately (which is knid of what you have done, I thnk); use  `m[i] <- b[X[i]]` with prior ` for(i in 1:2) {b[i] ~ dnorm(0, 200^(-2))}` . For this second notation you will need `X = factor(RailTrail$weekday))` in `jags.model`

Comment: ... re you comment. If oyu are including the intercept `a`, then `b` will have only one parameter so you only need to set the prior on `b`: `b ~ ... `

Comment: actually, I just ran you code but with `X = factor(RailTrail$weekday))` and it executes but you will notice that it is over-paramterised -- yo udont need `b[1] <- 0` if you include the intercept

Comment: interesting. I checked that `RailTrail$weekday` explicitly before so did not think of including it in the model statement explicitly. Thanks for the tip! Works now.

Answer (score 3):

as shared by [@user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418207/rjags-compilation-with-categorical-variable-throws-index-out-of-range-error?noredirect=1#comment110393707_62418207):

The code works with using explicit `X = factor(RailTrail$weekday))` in the compile statement, *i.e.,*

```r
# COMPILE the model
rail_jags_1 <- jags.model(
  textConnection(rail_model_1),
  data = list(Y = RailTrail$volume, X = factor(RailTrail$weekday)),
  inits = list(.RNG.name = "base::Wichmann-Hill", .RNG.seed = 10)
)
```